# How to save an array from serial port to arduino (Save in EEPROM memory)

Tags: python, arrays, arduino, serial-port, eeprom

I trying to implement a project and I'm running in some issues. Well, I need to send an array from Python to arduino and save the array at EEPROM memory. I did some tests to save just ONE element at EEPROM memory and it worked preety well.

But, When I try to send the whole array, the data at EEPROM are ALL wrong. I think maybe it's because the time needed to write data in EEPROM memory.

**Python**

```
for i in range(0,156):
    
    conexao.write(str(eeprom[i]).encode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(2)

conexao.close()
```

**Arduino**

```
#include <EEPROM.h>


String c;
int aux=0; 

const int STARTING_EEPROM_ADDRESS = 0;
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 156;
int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];

void writeIntArrayIntoEEPROM(int address, int numbers[],int element){
  
  int x = element;
  int addressIndex = address;
  

   
  EEPROM.write(addressIndex, numbers[x] >> 8);
  EEPROM.write(addressIndex + 1, numbers[x] & 0xFF);
  while(Serial.read() >= 0); // I hope it clean the serial buffer 
  

}
void readIntArrayFromEEPROM(int address, int numbers[], int arraySize)
{
  int addressIndex = address;
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
    numbers[i] = (EEPROM.read(addressIndex) << 8) + EEPROM.read(addressIndex + 1);
    addressIndex += 2;
  }
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  int newNumbers[ARRAY_SIZE];
  readIntArrayFromEEPROM(STARTING_EEPROM_ADDRESS, newNumbers, ARRAY_SIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
  {
    Serial.println(newNumbers[i]);
  }
//  Serial.println((EEPROM.read(0) << 8) + EEPROM.read(0 + 1));
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()>0){
    for (int i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) { 
      c=Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
      numbers[i]=c.toInt();
      writeIntArrayIntoEEPROM(aux, numbers[i], i);
      aux +=2;
      
        
   }
 }
}
```